# C Avoid cursor positioning on key press

Tags: c, terminal, key

I'm trying to implement a sort of terminal in C. I'm trying to build terminal history on up-down key pressure, but if I press those keys the cursor will go up (or down) one row. How to "control" this feature?

Edit:
Let's take an example:

```
fgets(cmd, sizeof(cmd), stdin);

    if (cmd[0] == '\033')
        if (cmd[2] == 'A')
            printf("up-arrow pressed!\n");
```

This code is horrible, but it is a good starting point. It works. The problem is that if you press the up arrow key (cursor), it moves on the upper row and print "up-arrow pressed!". How to avoid the cursor up-down movement without external libraries?

Comment: Without the code, it's impossible to answer this...

Comment: I would heavily recommend to use libreadline for that purpose. It provides a lot of features while being independent from specific terminal emulations

Comment: Exactly, the up down cursor, usually used in terminal for history. I read about library, which are really usefull, but I'm trying to build everything alone. Check question, I edited

Comment: I think that your history would be better to be a separate executable launched by your terminal implementation and that will use some libraries for managing keyboard inputs (e.g. ncurses or or readline). You will have then complete control on keyboard interrupts (and yes key up stroke will not be intercepted by the Terminal process).

Comment: Ok, then which terminal emulation? vt100? You have to send the control sequences for echo-off and to set a character-oriented mode

Comment: I have terminator, but I prefer to check a "global" solution

Comment: @Ctx No problem for disabling echo on tty, but what does "set a character-oriented mode" mean?

Comment: @AndreaMartinelli Usually you are in the **linemode**, where your program will receive data line by line (i.e. after pressing enter). But for this task, you need to be in **character mode**, so your program can process the input immediately after a character was typed (i.e. cursor-up). You can do this under unix with an appropriate call to `ioctl()`

Comment: @Ctx Thanks, this is a great idea. Can you post me some starting code? I can't find ioctl() source code

Comment: Why not use a ready-made library as most other programs.

Comment: @AndreaMartinelli I put something to start with in an answer, since the code is too big for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A real application would provide for exiting the program other than with a `^C`.  Here is an example, amending @ctx's sample to do this (and improving the handling of escape sequences), exiting when two escapes in a row are read:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main (void) {

        struct termios t, save;
        int last;
        tcgetattr(0, &t);
        save = t;
        t.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON);
        tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &t);

        while (1) {
                int ch = getchar();
                if (ch == '\033') {
                    if (last == ch)
                            break;
                        do {
                            last = ch;
                            ch = getchar();
                        } while (ispunct(ch) || isdigit(ch));
                        if (isalpha(ch)) {
                            printf("Got escape sequence: ");
                            switch (ch) {
                                case 'A':
                                        printf("Cursor up\n");
                                        break;
                                case 'B':
                                        printf("Cursor down\n");
                                        break;
                                case 'D':
                                        printf("Cursor left\n");
                                        break;
                                case 'C':
                                        printf("Cursor right\n");
                                        break;
                                default:
                                    printf("%c\n", ch);
                                    break;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                } else if (ch > 0) {
                        printf("Got %c\n", ch);
                }
            last = ch;
        }

        tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &save);
        return 0;
}
```

The equivalent (with different messages) is simpler in curses:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main (void) {
    int last = 0;

    filter();
    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    while (1) {
            int ch = getch();
            if (ch >= 0) {
                    if (ch >= KEY_MIN) {
                            printf("Got special key %s\r\n", keyname(ch));
                    } else {
                            if (ch == '\033' && last == ch)
                                    break;
                            printf("Got %s\r\n", unctrl(ch));
                    }
                    last = ch;
                    fflush(stdout);
            }
        }

        endwin();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: How did reading two escapes in a row not work before? I do not see where this is improved now.

Comment: @AndreaMartinelli If you use a library, you should use libreadline for that purpose, which is ncurses-based but achieves what you want on a higher level.

Comment: this line: `save = t;` is not going to work as expected because a termios is not an intrinsic C size/type.   suggest using `memcpy( &save, &t, sizeof(struct termios) )l`

Comment: struct-copy has worked in ANSI C for some time: I would use `memcpy` in the special cases where the types are not known to the compiler, or if the structure contained pointers.  (My comment about 2 escapes was about exiting the otherwise infinite-loop - fixed).

Answer (score 1):

For a starter, an example how you could initialize your terminal and some basic code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main (void) {

        struct termios t;
        tcgetattr(0, &t);
        t.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON);
        tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &t);

        while (1) {
                char ch = getchar();
                if (ch == '\x1b') {
                        do {
                                ch = getchar();
                        } while (!isalpha(ch));
                        printf("Got escape sequence: ");
                        switch (ch) {
                                case 'A':
                                        printf("Cursor up\n");
                                        break;
                                case 'B':
                                        printf("Cursor down\n");
                                        break;
                                case 'D':
                                        printf("Cursor left\n");
                                        break;
                                case 'C':
                                        printf("Cursor right\n");
                                        break;
                                default:
                                        printf("%c\n", ch);
                        }
                        // handle escape sequence
                } else {
                        printf("Got %c\n", ch);
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Now you have to output the typed characters and move around by *sending* appropriate escape sequences when you receive a cursor-* or some other control sequence (instead of the debug-`printf`s above). You have to closely keep track on your current screen-layout for that.

As I already suggested in my comments, this a very tedious work and apart from learning (or maybe embedded systems) I do not see a benefit compared to using libreadline or a similar API.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll try with a library, maybe it can be more powerfull and easy